# Access data in EventArgs Class

Tags: c#, arguments, eventargs

I am trying to access data store in ResultID from the following code:

```
public class ResultPanelEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string stringResultId = string.Empty;
    private int intRowIndex = -1;
    private string stringAnalysisName = string.Empty;
    private DateTime dateTimeAnalysisDateTime;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the row index of selected result.
    /// </summary>
    public int RowIndex
    {
        get { return intRowIndex; }
        set { intRowIndex = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the result id of selected result.
    /// </summary>
    public string ResultId
    {
        get { return stringResultId; }
        set { stringResultId = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time of the selected result.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime AnalysisDateTime
    {
        get { return dateTimeAnalysisDateTime; }
        set { dateTimeAnalysisDateTime = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the sample as Analysis name.
    /// </summary>
    public string AnalysisName
    {
        get { return stringAnalysisName; }
        set { stringAnalysisName = value; }
    }
};
```

I have a method to pull the info:

```
private string GetResultID(object sender, ResultPanelEventArgs e)
    {        


        string resultID = string.Empty;
        resultID = e.ResultId.ToString();
        return resultID;           

    }
```

but cannot seem to call that method (I get Argument errors). I am somewhat new to c# and have never worked with EventArgs so I don't even know if this is possible. Any advice on how to access the data stored here?

Per request here are three methods that appear to populate ResultId:

```
private ResultPanelEventArgs GetDataForTheGivenRowIndex(int intRowIndex)
    {
        ResultPanelEventArgs resultPanelEventArgs = new ResultPanelEventArgs();
        resultPanelEventArgs.RowIndex = intRowIndex;
        try
        {
            if (intRowIndex >= 0 && intRowIndex < dataGridViewResultView.Rows.Count)
            {
                object objectResultId = null;
                if (dataGridViewResultView.Columns.Contains("ColumnResultId") == true)
                {
                    objectResultId = dataGridViewResultView.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells["ColumnResultId"].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    objectResultId = dataGridViewResultView.Rows[intRowIndex].Tag;
                }
                if (objectResultId != null)
                {
                    resultPanelEventArgs.ResultId = objectResultId.ToString();
                }

                object objectAnalysisName = null;
                if (dataGridViewResultView.Columns.Contains("ColumnAnalysis") == true)
                {
                    objectAnalysisName = dataGridViewResultView.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells["ColumnAnalysis"].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    objectAnalysisName = dataGridViewResultView.Rows[intRowIndex].Tag;
                }
                if (objectAnalysisName != null)
                {
                    resultPanelEventArgs.AnalysisName = objectAnalysisName.ToString();
                }

                object objectAnalysisDateTime = null;
                if (dataGridViewResultView.Columns.Contains("ColumnDate") == true)
                {
                    objectAnalysisDateTime = dataGridViewResultView.Rows[intRowIndex].Cells["ColumnDate"].Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    objectAnalysisDateTime = dataGridViewResultView.Rows[intRowIndex].Tag;
                }
                if (objectAnalysisDateTime != null)
                {
                    resultPanelEventArgs.AnalysisDateTime = 
                             Utilities.ConvertStringToDateTime(objectAnalysisDateTime.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            resultPanelEventArgs = null;
            //Nothing to do
        }
        return resultPanelEventArgs;
    }
```

and

```
private ResultPanelEventArgs GetDataForTheGivenResultID(string stringResultId)
    {
        ResultPanelEventArgs resultPanelEventArgs = null;
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in dataGridViewResultView.Rows)
            {
                if (dataGridViewRow != null)
                {
                    if (dataGridViewRow.Index >= 0)
                    {
                        if (dataGridViewRow.Cells["ColumnResultId"] != null)
                        {
                            if (dataGridViewRow.Cells["ColumnResultId"].Value.ToString() == stringResultId)
                            {
                                //Create the ResultPanelEventArgs
                                object objectResultId = dataGridViewRow.Cells["ColumnResultId"].Value;
                                object objectAnalysisName = dataGridViewRow.Cells["ColumnAnalysis"].Value;
                                object objectAnalysisDateTime = dataGridViewRow.Cells["ColumnDate"].Tag;
                                resultPanelEventArgs = new ResultPanelEventArgs();

                                if (objectResultId != null)
                                {
                                    resultPanelEventArgs.RowIndex = dataGridViewRow.Index;
                                    resultPanelEventArgs.ResultId = objectResultId.ToString();
                                    resultPanelEventArgs.AnalysisName = objectAnalysisName.ToString();
                                    resultPanelEventArgs.AnalysisDateTime = (DateTime)objectAnalysisDateTime;
                                }

                                dataGridViewRow.Selected = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            resultPanelEventArgs = null;
            //Nothing to do
        }
        return resultPanelEventArgs;
    }
```

and

```
 private void dataGridViewResultList_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                this.result = this.GetResult(e.RowIndex);

                ResultPanelEventArgs resultPanelEventArgs = new ResultPanelEventArgs();
                resultPanelEventArgs.ResultId = this.result.Id.ToString();
                resultPanelEventArgs.RowIndex = this.dataGridViewResultList.SelectedRows[0].Index;

                if (this.DoubleClicked != null)
                {
                    this.DoubleClicked(sender, resultPanelEventArgs);
                }

                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UICommon.LogError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you also provide an example of where you're populating the ResultID property of the event argument?

Comment: neontapir, I added your requested methods.

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is an event handler. If you are using an event that uses the standard base class, but triggering it with the ResultPanelEventArgs, you will need to handle it with the base class EventArgs then cast them to the correct type.

```
private void HandleResultID(object sender, EventArgs args)
{        
    var e = (ResultPanelEventArgs) args;
    var resultID = e.ResultId.ToString();


    // Now do something with the ID. You cannot return it, because this is handling the click event.  

}
```

Update: To subscribe to an event (add an event handler to an event):

```
this.DoubleClicked += new EventHandler(HandleResultID);
```

Comment: But what arguments do I need to call the method? this.GetResultId() does not take 0 arguments.

Comment: @alex Yes, I overlooked that. willkk I guess this is not an event handler if you want to call it.

Comment: @willkk I see this is an event handler. The return type must be void.

Comment: Thanks guys. I made this a void method, but how do I call this method. What arguments are needed.

Comment: You don't call it. You trigger the event, which you are doing. You may not be adding the event handler to the event first.